# What will / should be the approach to questions given that different models respond differently to prompts?

Tags: discussion, tags

And that's not all: even different versions of "the same ML model" can respond very differently to the same prompts

For example, say someone wants to ask a question about how to achieve "X" behaviour (perhaps with a specific ML model "Y"). there are at least the two following options:

- Questions are not tied to any particular ML model and version. Answers are a stew of "If you are using this ML model, then you should..."
- Questions are for a specific ML model but any version of it. Each ML model has its own tag. Answers are a stew of "If you are using this version, then you should...".
- Questions are for a specific ML model and specific version of it. Each version of each ML model has its own tag. Perhaps there is duplication across related Q&A of information due to similarities between different versions of models

What are the pros and cons of various approaches? And how could tagging for each of them be approached?

Comment: I appreciate that this seems to be related to the argument I made on the main meta site.

Comment: If you want to give some simple examples, "cowboy shoot" is a term that usually refers to a picture framing that goes "the actor's mid-waist to right above their head" (so called because it would include the cowboy face and the gun they are pointing at someone). Many models will understand the term, some will try to give the character a gun and a cowboy hat.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly only joined this beta to see what issues were discussed before the site launched (I may deleted the account at a later time) and I only [answered this question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/23/61) to be able to reference it here.

As you can see the user there is using an online service to generate images.

From the question it is clear that different style choices produce different results and the prompt that works for one style doesn't work for the other.

It is also clear that despite the attempt to make the question generic any answer will have to be specific to the site they are using since generic methodologies don't work: someone even tried to link another question (lucky without flagging as a dupe, but don't hope for such luck when the site will have thousands of flag-farming users) about prompt weight but those proved ineffective.

Lastly it is also clear that the user has no way to know what the site is doing with their prompt: do every style map to the same model with an added prompt prefix or are they separate models? Do said model have version? Are them well known models publicly available or  are they specific for the site? Will result change as the site updates said models?

[I already mentioned this issue on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390509/171199): this site will be a versioning living hell.

Good luck, personally the only suggestion I can give is try to start with generic technology tags (example: Anything-Diffusion, Automatic etc) and then add versioning to the mix only when required (example: PonyDiffusion-v4, which use a prompt syntax different from previous versions).

Even so, prepare because it will be a mess. What will you do when a version of a model introduces a breaking changes in how to write a prompt that is maintained in latter ones? Create a prompt like "Model-V5+"? or even better "Model-V5-to-V7"? And how do you expect people to know when this is relevant if they are here to ask questions in the first place because they don't know how to write a prompt?

Alternatively you can decide to always specify the version and move the problem around: now you have a question about "Model-v7" and don't know if it was still valid for "Model-v6" or "Model-v8".

Someone tried to claim that this is no different from how software packages work, but they missed a critical point. Software is made with a bigger intent to not break things and therefore breaking changes are limited by design. Models? You are just finetuning or remixing your previous release: even the creator can't know what the result will be beforehand....