# Are questions about GenAI-related history on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I can think of some questions about history of each individual GenAI tool and other related topics. For example,

- When did ChatGPT start to support Thai language?
- Which GenAI tool first invented the inpainting feature?
- What was the first impactful event that makes GenAI so popular?

Are these types of questions on-topic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen this question before. I wonder if the previous question was deleted.

Comment: I asked it on Teams [here](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/prompt-design-stakeholders/q/126/7); it wasn't answered there, but I mentioned that I was personally leaning towards such questions being on-topic.

Comment: For a comparison to a site I've been personally involved on: [RPG.SE] also allows questions about the history of a particular RPG or of RPGs in general, and comparisons between different editions of the same RPG. So in general, questions about the history of GenAI in general or a particular GenAI seem like they could potentially be allowed here (depending on the question). They could even have a tag used to group them together, e.g. `[history]`. (I'm not sure if a tag like RPG's [edition-comparison] tag would make sense here, but that's up to the community.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that [“different versions of "the same model" can respond very differently”](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/10), and many GenAI systems are proprietary [SaaSS](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/who-does-that-server-really-serve.html), I think it would be wise to allow history questions, as necessary context to understand months-old answers in this rapidly-changing field.

Specifically, I think we should allow “history of X” for all on-topic X.

There's potential overlap with other sites, but nothing too egregious:

- [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is for general history. There's [not a notability requirement “as such”](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3999/21544).
- [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/10336), for academic / technical questions.
- [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/278) for the history of the *very* old stuff (which might not even be on-topic here).
- [Music Stack Exchange's [history] tag](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2881/44151).
- [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3847/60962), for GenAI qua a historical technique.

Answer (score 2):

> When did ChatGPT start to support Thai language?

Sounds fine to me. Objective.

> Which GenAI tool first invented the inpainting feature?

Same thing. Objective, as long as "inpainting" has a well-known and agreed upon definition, or a clear definition is provided in the question post.

> What was the first impactful event that makes GenAI so popular?

This can be opinion based, so I'm not sure if it's a good fit. Add to that that popularity can grow over time. So when do you define when it has "become popular"?

---

I think there can be questions that are a good fit, but not all of them will be. I suggest a case-by-case evaluation.

Comment: Agreed. I think questions about GenAI history in general are okay in principle, but obviously they could still be closed for other reasons such as being opinion-based/unclear/too broad.