# How to judge if a question is asking the off-topic "ready-to-go" prompt?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, specific-tag

I would like to know how to judge if a question is asking for/about a prompt that is considered too niche that it will not be useful to wider audience; hence [off-topic](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-on-topic-on-genai-se).

> Questions asking for "ready to go" prompts. On GenAI, questions should
> seek explanation. Off-the-shelf prompts on specific topics tend to be
> unhelpful for others, become obsolete quickly, and generally aren't a
> good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A format. Besides, there's a lot of
> flexibility when interacting with AI, and specific prompts will
> produce different results each time they are used.

Here are some examples of questions currently with [prompt-design](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design) tag.

1. [How can I effectively create a prompt to generate realistic limbs and fingers using Leonardo.ai?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-can-i-effectively-create-a-prompt-to-generate-realistic-limbs-and-fingers-us)
2. [Is it possible to prompt ChatGPT into playing a competent game of hangman?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-it-possible-to-prompt-chatgpt-into-playing-a-competent-game-of-hangman)
3. [Some of my important points being ignored in text-to-image generation. How to emphasize it to be in the image?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/21/some-of-my-important-points-being-ignored-in-text-to-image-generation-how-to-em)
4. [How to make ChatGPT responses about calendar/dates accurate?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-to-make-chatgpt-responses-about-calendar-dates-accurate)
5. [How do I create the start of a forest fire?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-do-i-create-the-start-of-a-forest-fire)

In my opinion, 1 and 3 seem to be generic prompts that may be useful to wide audience. However, 2, 4, and 5 are worth considering each or any of them are in the realm of "ready-to-go" prompt. FWIW, 3 and 4 are my own questions.

Comment: I believe this part of the scope was to deter lazy "give me the codez" questions.  Maybe it could use rephrasing.

Comment: another: [How can I draw three cups in a row, the middle one blue, the outside ones red, and with one red cup taller than the other two cups?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/66/33)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually two possibilities here:

- **A request for a prompt**:  "Give me an Midjourney prompt for a dog on a yacht."
- **A request for genAI results**:  "Give me an AI-generated image of a dog on a yacht."

These are effortless (or no-effort-indicated) requests for an unpaid service.  "Do this for me."

While admittedly it would be inconsiderate to ask for free services, ***would either of these requests actually be that big of a problem?***  Nobody is obligated to answer such questions, but maybe some users would like to answer such questions, perhaps as a kind of puzzle, and the answers it attracts might still be creative or useful in unexpected ways, which could lead to other questions or be referenced when writing answers.  (It reminds me a bit of [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).).  It is also nice to have some "low hanging apples" questions so new users can start participating and earning rep.  Oh, and I'd also like to point out that some genAI services are not universally available.

We could just downvote the bad ones, and if no-one wants to answer them, they'll quickly drop off the front page and be auto-deleted (roomba) down the line, and if someone actually wants to answer it, that's fine too.  In some cases, we can close them as duplicates, if the method in one answer can solve a "do this for me" request.

Thus far, I would say we are yet to get any "do this for me" requests (we're getting good faith questions, nowhere near the boundary where it begins to feel exploitative), and we're not at risk of drowning in them any time soon.  I'm not seeing Reddit sites being flooded with them either.  **It seems the lazy approach is asking genAI, not GenAI**; if I make the request at [pollinations.ai](https://image.pollinations.ai/prompt/Give%20me%20an%20AI-generated%20image%20of%20a%20dog%20on%20a%20yacht.), it gives me:

> [image: dog on a yacht generated by pollinations.ai]
> <sub>(Who's a good doggy?  You are.  Yes, you are.)</sub>

All in all, currently this problem is still hypothetical, and maybe it's not worth fixing hypothetical problems just yet.  So **I suggest we delete this paragraph from the scope**, and if one day it becomes an actual problem (e.g., if "do this for me" requests become too frequent) we can figure it out then, and probably by that time we will have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: I like this POV. Especially because likely the first step in getting any output from a genAI is just asking it. I imagine anyone bringing those here is after something specific and can't quite figure it out. So while they might be "do this for me" prompts they might actually be unique puzzle-esque questions.

Comment: I think "how" questions are good and fine. I don't think "just give me the answer I don't care about how you get it" is useful for a long-term, reusable-value knowledge base.

Comment: That is a good dog. [Asking for a bad dog](https://image.pollinations.ai/prompt/Give%20me%20an%20AI-generated%20image%20of%20a%20bad%20dog%20on%20a%20yacht) results in a dog way too big for that yacht.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rebecca that maybe reframing it a bit could help so I took a stab at it. I feel like this gives it some better framing to make it easier for users to better understand how to not make a "Ready-to-Go" prompt.

### Identifying Off-Topic "Ready-to-Go" Prompts

- Avoid Specific Prompts: Ensure that questions do not solely intend to seek pre-made prompts intended for specific tasks. Instead, questions should encourage answers to provide explanations and general approaches to broad application.
- Consider Audience Relevance: Questions should have a wide capability that can benefit a diverse audience. Highly specialized prompts likely won't be useful to others.
- Flexibility: Questions that embrace prompts that offer versatility and produce varied results should be the framework. Avoid rigid prompts with limited applications.

---

Using the above framework, I evaluated the sample questions as follows:

**Question 1: On-Topic**
This is currently a big problem with image generators, at least to my knowledge. So, this question seems like it could be relevant to a broad audience. It begets answers by encouraging appropriate prompt design by drawing attention to the prompt and the words you shouldn’t use. While it's about hands, figure distortion is common and is bound to pop up frequently for users. Answers to this question could likely be applied to multiple handfuls of questions. So, it's not just asking for a specific prompt.

---

**Question 2: On-Topic**
I don’t see this one as needing a ready-to-go prompt. Rather, it is a general question about the capabilities of ChatGPT. The question could be valuable to a broad audience. I see it as relevant to the general use of ChatGPT. It could be helpful to others interested in using a GenAI chatbot to play games. It uses a prompt, quite a few of them that could produce varied outputs, as ChatGPT could produce various outcomes while playing the game. I don’t see it as too rigid of a prompt, as it could be applied to different game types or variations of a typical hangman game.

---

**Question 3: On-Topic**
This question isn’t for a specific task. Instead, it's asking how to emphasize certain aspects of image generation. Answers to this question would provide explanations and generalized approaches for broad application to possibly multiple GenAI tools. This question is helpful to many users regarding what is possibly a common issue in image generation. I think it's a flexible question as it invites prompts that offer versatility to solve problems like these. It encourages answers that provide varied solutions to the problem of emphasizing some aspects and ignoring others in image generation.

---

**Question 4: On topic-ish?**
This question wants a general approach to improve the accuracy of ChatGPT's responses about calendar dates. This is pretty specific, I can’t really speculat of a way that this wouldn’t be a question with really one answer, with maybe slight variations. Maybe that is good enough? Regardless of its specificity, the question could be relevant to a broad audience. I could see more than a couple of situations where people might be interested in why their calendar dates are off, but all for the same reason. It's terrible at math unless you are super specific. So I see this as flexible to a point; different applications could need a solution that varies slightly but is ultimately conceptually the same thing. So, this question could get a few good answers, and the rest become duplicates. I see it as flexible, as it won't always be the exact solution. There is a possibility for some variation in solutions that could help improve the accuracy of outputs around calendar dates.

---

**Question 5: On Topic**
This one would require answers to provide explanations and general approaches to creating an image representing the start of a forest fire, which has broad application. I see this as a Q&A that could have high variance. This seems like a type of question where an image/object is in an incomplete state or early one. I could see a lot of situations where this could be an applicable question where the prompt would need to be different due to the physics of the object or setting in question, such as The beginning of a weather pattern, melting water, or something dry. These are all examples of state change, and the prompts would not necessarily be specific or relatively similar. The art-oriented questions to me have broad application to many people; they could come up numerous times with slightly nuanced variations and goals but with a similar category being “state change,” a term I have made up... These prompts wouldn’t be specialized as many people could benefit from them. I see this as a relatively flexible question with answers that could vary quite a bit.

---

Comment: genuine question- did you take a stab at this? or did ChatGPT take a stab at this?

Comment: @starball Haha, I did write it myself. I did use Grammarly to help edit though. In a past job, I wrote well over 100 help center articles for technical how-to guides for software though, I can sound extremely robotic.

Comment: I don't think the example is good at demonstrating the point... or if it is, I don't think the point on outdating is good. Just version tag the question to a specific model version. Just because new model version are released doesn't mean that nobody uses the old model anymore. Unless the same version of a model itself changes rapidly, this is not something I think we need to be concerned about. See also [What will / should be the approach to questions given that different models respond differently to prompts?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/33)

Comment: Thats a fair point, and so is the point made there. I suppose its more likely that there is value in keeping different versions than not. I will edit to remove that point, but leave the others.

Comment: It'd be nice to hear your evaluation of the listed examples in the question post, based on the criteria you've laid out, and how those questions could be improved to be on-topic if off-topic. It's not yet very clear to me how to apply these criteria objectively.

Comment: @SpencerG Like starball mentioned, I also would like to see how this reframed guideline works. Can you evaluate the example list in the question? Which one is on-topic and which one is not, and why?

Comment: I applied the framework to those questions, though the original framing could be just as easily used to come to the same conclusions, at least for me, I didn't see myself coming to different conclusions.

Comment: If the useful part of Q1 is addressing figure distortion, then why not make the question about figure distortion? Also, thoughts on [this](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/66/33)? My general thought is that if these questions are okay because of their possible more general applications, then searchability is a current problem with the way they are titled. How are people looking for the generalized problem going to find these in search results?

Comment: @starball Well, figure distortion is a phrase I made up for this, so I don't know that it would make sense today to use that phrasing. I am saying this as just a user, but I think it might just have to be allowed for the time being. Otherwise, we are taking on the burden of trying to get an entire industry to adopt a certain vernacular. Of course, we can just make edits where we see them as necessary.